# SQL group and condition sum in the last row

Tags: sql, hana

I have several items which belongs to different group, some are unknown group.
I need the sum of each group by date.
I just try below SQL but still not exactly what I want:

```
with A as (
SELECT PG, EMANAGER_DATE,
  CASE WHEN (EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-09') THEN SUM(NET_VALUE_USD) ELSE 0 END AS "2021-09",
  CASE WHEN (EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-10') THEN SUM(NET_VALUE_USD) ELSE 0 END AS "2021-10",
  CASE WHEN (EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-11') THEN SUM(NET_VALUE_USD) ELSE 0 END AS "2021-11",
  CASE WHEN (EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-12') THEN SUM(NET_VALUE_USD) ELSE 0 END AS "2021-12"
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY PG, EMANAGER_DATE
)
select PG, max("2021-09") AS "2021-09", max("2021-10") AS "2021-10", max("2021-11") AS "2021-11", max("2021-12") AS "2021-12" from A GROUP BY PG
```

DB: **SAP HANA**

Data:

| Item | PG | NET_VALUE_USD | EMANAGER_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 2021-09 |
| 2 | 1 | 200 | 2021-10 |
| 3 | 2 | 300 | 2021-09 |
| 4 | 2 | 400 | 2021-09 |
| 5 | 3 | 500 | 2021-09 |
| 6 | 3 | 200 | 2021-11 |
| 7 | 3 | 300 | 2021-11 |
| 8 |  | 900 | 2021-09 |

Expected result:

| PG | 2021-09 | 2021-10 | 2021-11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ? | 900 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 0 |
| 2 | 700 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 500 | 0 | 500 |
| total | 2200 | 200 | 500 |

Comment: It looks like sometimes they values are added, other times they're reset. What's the logic?

Comment: I update my data, they values are added.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea if you added some text in your Question. It kind of looks like an unexplained Jira-ticket instead of a Stack Overflow Question.

Comment: Were do you need this expected result? It's to be displayed, or to be stored somewhere? And what did you try yet?

Comment: To be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust your query and use `GROUPING SETS`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN GROUPING(PG) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE PG END) as PG,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-09' THEN NET_VALUE_USD ELSE 0 END) AS "2021-09",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-10' THEN NET_VALUE_USD ELSE 0 END) AS "2021-10",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-11' THEN NET_VALUE_USD ELSE 0 END) AS "2021-11",
       SUM(CASE WHEN EMANAGER_DATE = '2021-12' THEN NET_VALUE_USD ELSE 0 END) AS "2021-12"
FROM _SYS_BIC."APP_SCM/ZCV_APP_SCM_CTOS_PARENT_UNCONFIRMED_BACKLOG_P"
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (PG), () );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, how can I do if I have lots of `EMANAGER_DATE` by using `pivot` ?

Comment: @YuTing . . . If you want the summary row, I think you are better off with this approach.